# IntelliJ cannot find maven-assembly-plugin im pom.xml

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

So, I just installed IntelliJ on my new Computer and wanted to work on an old Project, but now IntelliJ can't find the maven-assembly-plugin anymore.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main-class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried turning on the "Use plugin registry"-Option unsuccessfully and tried multiple reimports, but the assembly-plugin won't import. I also checked the .m2 folder, but it does not contain an assembly-plugin file. Furthermore, I am pretty sure the problem is located in some option in IntelliJ, but I really have no clue where this option is because I am not very familiar with IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in your pom, not IntelliJ.  I've used it for 16 years.  You shouldn't need to turn on anything to use that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is switching from the maven-assembly-plugin to the maven-shade-plugin and this worked fine for me. But I am not sure why the other plugin did not work.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main-class</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```